# Teradata: varchar to timestamp

Tags: sql, teradata

how to convert a varchar value like `19-JAN-18 06.53.31.000000 AM` to timestamp? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_timestamp()`.  Something like this:

```
select to_timestamp('19-JAN-18 06.53.31.000000 AM', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS.FF6 AM')
```

This uses Oracle's format model.  I'm not sure if Teradata's is exactly the same.

Comment: It's `MON` instead of `MMM`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
sel cast(cast(cast('19-JAN-18 06.53.31.000000 AM' as varchar(50)) as timestamp(0) format 'mm/dd/yyyyBhh:mi:ss') as timestamp(0));
```